# Trigger event after seconds rather than minutes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am creating a Google Script that includes this code:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("fetchTweets")
         .timeBased()
         .everyMinutes(1)
         .create();
```

How can I change this to trigger the event every ten seconds instead of once every minute?

Comment: `.everyMinutes((1/60)*10)`, assuming it doesn't require integers

Comment: This is the documentation for everyMinutes: Sets the trigger to be created to fire on an interval of the passed in number of minutes which must be one of 1, 5, 10, 15 or 30.  So I don't think it will accept a fractional number.

Answer (score 3):

A solution similar to this should work for you, it's working correctly in my test area:

```
function callSixTimes() {
  fetchTweets();
  for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    fetchTweets()
  }
}

function generateTriggers() {

  var everyMinute = ScriptApp.newTrigger("callSixTimes")
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();
}
```

According to [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/BySlaSPrBEY) in google groups, this appears to be the recommended way to achieve this level of granularity.  Please note that even after the trigger is deleted, the function with settimeout in it may continue to fire until it finishes looping.

Comment: Strangely nothing happens when I add this code in :( I tried logging the function 'callSixTimes' too but it is never called.

Comment: Are you making sure you are running "generateTriggers" under the Run menu?  If you just hit "Run" button that looks like a Play symbol then you'll just call whatever function is set in the menu on toolbar.  When you run the script, what does the little popup say?

Comment: I hit run like you told me to but there is no popup?

Comment: What's the context that you're running this in?  Is it a spreadsheet, or a script project, or something else?